# OpenVPN server: how to tell if server is listening/working?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to set up an OpenVPN server on an EC2 instance.  There doesn't seem to be any Ubuntu documentation for OpenVPN, so I'm mostly following the instructions here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

My Android phone reports "connection refused".  Tunnelblick says "TLS handshake failed".

I would like to check that OpenVPN actually is listening on my server.  But there's no OpenVPN process running - it uses systemd.  And it uses UDP rather than TCP, so the usual trick of connecting with telnet doesn't work.  Can anyone tell me how I can verify that OpenVPN is actually listening?

The server is running Ubuntu Trusty.

Answer (score 3):

I got OpenVPN working.  To answer my question:

There should be a server running like this:

```
$ ps auxww | grep openvpn
root       536  0.0  0.5  35672  5108 ?        Ss   00:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-server --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --script-security 2 --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/server.pid
```

In my case there wasn't due to a misconfiguration.  It's fairly obvious, but for the record: to find openvpn problems in the syslog:

```
sudo service openvpn stop
sudo service openvpn start
sudo tail /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Glad you got it to work. Some of the Android flavors have issues with VPN connections.  I had no problem with 4.2.2, a huge struggle with 5.1.1

Comment: For the record, this is working fine for me with Android 5.1 and OpenVPN for Android 0.6.63.

Comment: I got it to work with 5.1 but I had to use a different client on the droid.